# How to make has_many work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Models:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

.

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :games
end
```

Migrations:

```
class CreateManufacturers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :manufacturers do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

.

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :manufacturer, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

When I enter `m = Game.find(2).manufacturer` this works and gives me the manufacturer name. But when I give `g = Manufacturer.find(1).games` console throws many errors. Why does not the `has_many` work?

Or

How do I get all the games developed by the 1st manufacturer?

Error shown:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `games' for #<Manufacturer:0x007f996dc75368>
```

Comment: What errors you got? Please post it in the question.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Try restarting the server.

Comment: @Pavan: Yes now it works